# My Photos.app starts on system startup

Tags: icloud, photos, startup

Apple's new Photos.app starts on every system startup although there is no configuration settings for system startup.

**Here is my checklist:**

- Users & Groups > Login Items (There is no config for Photos)
- Right click photos in Dock > Options > Launch on system startup (There is no config for Photos)

**Here is my another what I did**

- Disabling and re-enabling iCloud Photos
- Repairing Photos library from this [tutorial](http://osxdaily.com/2015/05/21/repair-photos-library-photos-app-mac-os-x/)
- If Dropbox affect Photos for starting at system launch, I disable Dropbox's photos settings.

How can I prevent Photos.app on system startup without deleting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a SD card or a device which stores photos plugged in your Mac.

To prevent Photos from auto-opening, follow these instructions:

> - Connect the iPhone, camera, SD card, etc to the Mac and let Photos app launch itself as usual
> - Under the “Import” tab of Photos app, look in the upper left corner to find the device name, this will indicate which hardware will no
>     longer automatically activate Photos app
> - Click the checkbox so that “Open Photos for this device” is no longer selected (likewise, toggling this on would enable Photos app to
>     open itself again automatically when this device is connected)
> - Quit out of Photos app, the change is immediate for that device – this can be switched back at any time in the same OS X Photos app
>
> [image]

Via: http://osxdaily.com/2015/05/31/stop-photos-opening-automatically-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 0):

First, check whether you have any external devices connected to your mac. If there are no external devices, keep the Photos app in Dock and Right-click -> Options -> Open at login(Uncheck if it's checked).